# moving mouse by a detected object in python

Tags: python, mouse

The thing I want to do is like this:
My webcam reads the frame continously and detect an object that I trained my program for.
My program successfully detects that object.

But, I want to move the mouse the direction I moved that object
My program is in python.

Please, Suggest some Ideas or any tools.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: On which operating system?

Comment: Windows 8, I want to also handle other mouse events like lefclick and rightclick